# Solutions of general matrix ODEs

Tags: integration, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

**The Question**
$\newcommand{\img}{\operatorname{img}}$
$\newcommand{\bm}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}$

I am self-studying solutions of matrix ODEs. Below I have written the cases I know how to deal with, but I have some trouble with formalising the higher order ODE case when the matrix $\bm{B}_{m+1}$ is singular. Similarly I am not sure how to deal with the case with $\bm{A}(t,\bm{u}(t))$ so that I may write the solution in terms of some transition matrix (or whether that is even feasible). Also can I claim that the transition matrix $\bm{\Psi}$ is symmetric/Hermitian if $\bm{A}$ is symmetric/Hermitian? Based on the Peano-Baker series expansion that seem to be the case. Comprehensive references would be great, especially application/engineering/computationally oriented ones.

**Constant Coefficients**

The simplest matrix ODE I can think of is one with a constant coefficient matrix $\bm{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$:

$$d_t\bm{u}(t) = \bm{A}\bm{u}(t) + \bm{b}(t) \implies \bm{u}(T) = \bm{\exp}(T\bm{A})\bm{u}(0) + \int_0^T\bm{\exp}((T-t)\bm{A})\bm{b}(t)\,dt,$$

where the matrix exponential can be evaluated as $\bm{\exp}(t\bm{A}) = \bm{P}\bm{\exp}(t\bm{J})\bm{P}^{-1}$, where $\bm{A} = \bm{P}\bm{J}\bm{P}^{-1}$ is the Jordan decomposition of $\bm{A}$ (it is just the eigendecomposition in the simple case when $\bm{A}$ is non-defective). The above is derived as follows:

\begin{align}
d_t \bm{u}(t) &= \bm{A}\bm{u}(t) + \bm{b}(t) \\
\bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})d_t\bm{u}(t) &= \bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})\bm{A}\bm{u}(t) +\bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})\bm{b}(t)  \\ 
\bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})d_t\bm{u}(t) - \bm{A}\bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})\bm{u}(t) &= \bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})\bm{b}(t) \\
\bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})d_t\biggl(\bm{u}(t)\biggr) + d_t\biggl(\bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})\biggr)\bm{u}(t) &=\bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})\bm{b}(t)\\
d_t\biggl(\bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})\bm{u}(t)\biggr) &= \bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})\bm{b}(t) \\
\int_{0}^{T}d_t\biggl(\bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})\bm{u}(t)\biggr)\,dt &= \int_0^T \bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})\bm{b}(t)\,dt \\
\bm{\exp}(-T\bm{A})\bm{u}(T)-\exp(0\bm{A})\bm{u}(0) &=\int_0^T \bm{\exp}(-t\bm{A})\bm{b}(t)\,dt \\
\bm{u}(T) &= \bm{\exp}(T\bm{A})\bm{u}(0) + \int_0^T \bm{\exp}((T-t)\bm{A})\bm{b}(t)\,dt.
\end{align}

**Commuting Time-Dependent Matrix**

Things become harder when $\bm{A}$ is time-dependent: $\bm{A}(t) \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Specifically if I multiply both sides by $\bm{\exp}\left(-\int_{0}^T\bm{A}(s)\,ds\right)$ then for the third step I would need that the matrices commute:

$$\bm{\exp}\left(-\int_{0}^T\bm{A}(s)\,ds\right)\bm{A}(t) = \bm{A}(t)\bm{\exp}\left(-\int_{0}^T\bm{A}(s)\,ds\right).$$

This is true if $\bm{A}(t)\bm{A}(s) = \bm{A}(s)\bm{A}(t)$ for $0\leq s,t\leq T$ but does not hold in general. If it holds the solution is:

$$\bm{u}(T) = \bm{\exp}\left(\int_0^T\bm{A}(s)\,ds\right)\bm{u}(0) + \int_0^T\bm{\exp}\left(\int_t^T\bm{A}(s)\,ds\right)\bm{b}(t)\,dt.$$

In the special case where only the eigenvalues of $\bm{A}$ are functions of time but the eigenvectors are not, I can efficiently compute the exponential of the integral as:

$$\bm{\exp}\left(\int_a^b \bm{A}(t)\,dt\right) = \bm{P}\bm{\exp}\left(\int_a^b \bm{J}(t)\,dt\right)\bm{P}^{-1}.$$

**Non-Commuting Time-Dependent Matrix**

There supposedly exist cases when:

$$\bm{\exp}\left(-\int_{0}^T\bm{A}(s)\,ds\right)\bm{A}(t) \ne \bm{A}(t)\bm{\exp}\left(-\int_{0}^T\bm{A}(s)\,ds\right).$$

In such a scenario step three of the initial derivation is invalid. The solution can nevertheless be written in terms of a transition matrix $\bm{\Psi}(s,t)$:

$$\bm{u}(T) = \bm{\Psi}(T,0)\bm{u}(0) + \int_0^T\bm{\Psi}(T,t)\bm{b}(t)\,dt,$$

with the following properties:

\begin{align}
d_s \bm{\Psi}(s,t) &= \bm{A}(s)\bm{\Psi}(s,t) \\
d_t \bm{\Psi}(s,t) &= -\bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{A}(t) \\
\bm{\Psi}(s,t) &= \bm{\Psi}(s,r)\bm{\Psi}(r,t) \\
\bigl(\bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bigr)^{-1} &= \bm{\Psi}(t,s) \\
\bm{\Psi}(t,t) &= \bm{I}.
\end{align}

The derivation is carried out by using $\bm{\Psi}(s,t)$ as an integrating factor:

\begin{align}
d_t \bm{u}(t) &= \bm{A}(t)\bm{u}(t) + \bm{b}(t) \\
\bm{\Psi}(s,t)d_t\bm{u}(t) &= \bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{A}(t)\bm{u}(t) +\bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{b}(t)  \\ 
\bm{\Psi}(s,t)d_t\bm{u}(t) - \bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{A}(t)\bm{u}(t) &= \bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{b}(t) \\
\bm{\Psi}(s,t)d_t\biggl(\bm{u}(t)\biggr) + d_t\biggl(\bm{\Psi}(s,t)\biggr)\bm{u}(t) &=\bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{b}(t)\\
d_t\biggl(\bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{u}(t)\biggr) &= \bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{b}(t) \\
\int_{0}^{T}d_t\biggl(\bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{u}(t)\biggr)\,dt &= \int_0^T \bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{b}(t)\,dt \\
\bm{\Psi}(s,T)\bm{u}(T) - \bm{\Psi}(s,0)\bm{u}(0) &= \int_0^T \bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{b}(t)\,dt  \\
\bm{u}(T) &=  \left(\bm{\Psi}(s,T)\right)^{-1}\bm{\Psi}(s,0)\bm{u}(0) + \left(\bm{\Psi}(s,T)\right)^{-1}\int_0^T \bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{b}(t)\,dt  \\
\bm{u}(T) &=  \bm{\Psi}(T,s)\bm{\Psi}(s,0)\bm{u}(0) + \int_0^T \bm{\Psi}(T,s)\bm{\Psi}(s,t)\bm{b}(t)\,dt  \\
\bm{u}(T) &=  \bm{\Psi}(T,0)\bm{u}(0) + \int_0^T \bm{\Psi}(T,t)\bm{b}(t)\,dt.
\end{align}

The first identity is necessary for the ODE to be satisfied:

$$d_t \bm{u}(t) = d_t \bm{\Psi}(t,0)\bm{u}(0) = \bm{A}(t)\bm{\Psi}(t,0)\bm{u}(0) = \bm{A}(t) \bm{u}(0).$$

The property $\bm{\Psi}(t,t) = \bm{I}$ is necessary so that $\bm{u}(t)=\bm{u}(t)$, and the rest I used for the integration.

From what I read [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix#Peano%E2%80%93Baker_series) the transition matrix can be formed from the Peano-Baker series:

$$\bm{\Psi}(s,t) = \bm{I} + \int_s^t \bm{A}(\sigma_1) \,d\sigma_1 + \int_{s}^t\int_s^t \bm{A}(\sigma_1)\bm{A}(\sigma_2)\,d\sigma_2 d\sigma_1 + \ldots,$$

or equivalently from [the Magnus expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion) $\bm{\Psi}(s,t) = \bm{\exp}(\bm{\Omega}(s,t))$ with

$$\bm{\Omega}(s,t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \bm{\Omega}_k(s,t),$$

where the $\bm{\Omega}_k$ are given as:

\begin{align}
\bm{\Omega}_1(s,t) &= \int_s^t \bm{A}(\sigma_1)\,d\sigma_1 \\
\bm{\Omega}_2(s,t) &= \frac{1}{2}\int_s^t\int_s^t [\bm{A}(\sigma_1),\bm{A}(\sigma_2)] \,d\sigma_2 d\sigma_1 \\
\bm{\Omega}_3(s,t) &= \frac{1}{6}\int_s^t\int_s^t\int_s^t [\bm{A}(\sigma_1),[\bm{A}(\sigma_2),\bm{A}(\sigma_3)]] + [\bm{A}(\sigma_3),[\bm{A}(\sigma_2),\bm{A}(\sigma_1)]] \,d\sigma_3 d\sigma_2 d\sigma_1,
\end{align}

and so on (the recursive procedure is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion#Magnus_generator)).

On an unrelated note, I believe that $\bm{\Psi}$ is symmetric/Hermitian provided that $\bm{A}$ is symmetric/Hermitian, since the terms in the Peano-Baker expansion are of the form:

$$\int_{s}^t \ldots \int_s^t \bm{A}(t_1)\ldots \bm{A}(t_n) \,dt_n\ldots dt_1,$$

Then I can extract the following terms $\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \bm{A}(t_{\sigma(1)}) \ldots \bm{A}(t_{\sigma(n)})$ which ought to be symmetric/Hermitian if $\bm{A}(r)$ is symmetric/Hermitian for $r\in [s,t]$.

**Higher Order ODEs**

Let $\bm{B}_i \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and consider the ODE:
$$-\bm{B}_{m+1} (d_t^{m+1} \bm{u})(t) + \bm{B}_{m}(d_t^{m}\bm{u})(t) + \ldots + \bm{B}_0 \bm{u}(t) + \bm{c}(t) = \bm{0}.$$

If $\bm{B}_{m+1}$ is invertible then this can be rewritten as:

$$(d_t^{m+1} \bm{u})(t) = \sum_{j=0}^{m}\bm{B}_{m+1}^{-1}\bm{B}_j (d^j_t \bm{u})(t) + \bm{B}_{m+1}^{-1}\bm{c}(t) = \sum_{j=0}^m \bm{A}_j (d^j_t \bm{u})(t) + \bm{b}(t).$$

Furthermore, using the substitution $\bm{u}_{j+1} = d_t \bm{u}_j$ for $0\leq j \leq m-1$, I can rewrite this as the first order ODE system:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
d_t \bm{u}_0 \\
\vdots \\
d_t \bm{u}_{m-1} \\
d_t \bm{u}_m
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\bm{0}& \bm{I} & \bm{0} & \ldots &\bm{0} \\
\vdots& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots& \vdots \\
\bm{0}& \ldots & \bm{0} & \bm{I}& \bm{0} \\
\bm{0}& \ldots & \bm{0}& \bm{0} & \bm{I} \\
\bm{A}_0 & \ldots & \bm{A}_{m-2}& \bm{A}_{m-1} & \bm{A}_m
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\bm{u}_0 \\
\vdots \\
\bm{u}_m
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
\bm{0} \\ \vdots \\ \bm{0} \\ \bm{b}(t)
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Then the problem is of the form $d_t\bm{v}(t) = \bm{M}\bm{v}(t) + \bm{d}(t)$ which I already know how to solve. If I make any of the matrices time dependent then I get $d_t \bm{v}(t) = \bm{M}(t)\bm{v}(t) + \bm{d}(t)$ which I also know how to solve.

If $\bm{B}_{m+1}$ is not invertible the above is not valid anymore. I can however take a basis $\bm{U}_{\img}$ for the image of $\bm{B}_m$ and a basis $\bm{U}_{\ker}$ for the kernel of $\bm{B}^T_{m+1}$ and split the problem in these by multiplying by $\bm{U}_{\img}^*$ and $\bm{U}_{\ker}^*$ from the left. Then one of those problems would be again of the "non-singular" type that I already discussed, and the other would be of one (or more) orders lower. I am not quite sure how to develop that beyond the above idea, especially w.r.t. how the solutions should look like. Could it be that one can use a generalised inverse in this case?

**"Quasi"-Linear ODEs**

One can also consider an ODE system of the form $d_t \bm{u}(t) = \bm{A}(t,\bm{u}(t))\bm{u}(t) + \bm{b}(t)$. I could of course just integrate both sides to get:

$$\bm{u}(T) = \bm{u}(0) + \int_0^T\bm{A}(t,\bm{u}(t))\bm{u}(t)\,dt + \int_0^T\bm{b}(t)\,dt,$$

although this doesn't feel very satisfactory. Is there some way to formulate this in terms of a transition matrix as for the time dependent case? My only idea is to Taylor expand around zero and then

$$\bm{A}(t,\bm{u}(t)) = \bm{A}(0,\bm{u}(0)) + d_t(\bm{A}(\cdot,\cdot))(0,\bm{u}(0))t + O(t^2),$$

where

$$d_t(\bm{A}(\cdot,\cdot))(0,\bm{u}(0)) = d_t\bm{A}(0,\bm{u}(0)) + d_\bm{u} \bm{A}(0,\bm{u}(0))(d_t\bm{u})(0).$$

But I am not sure how to develop that further. I suppose that it is ok to ignore the $O(t^2)$ terms in the integration since those would disappear with the limit.